# Module Calendar can't be installed with Wordpress

Tags: extension, installation, calendar

we use WordPress 6.2.2 and CiviCRM 5.58.1.
When I try to install the extension "Calendar"
[image]

I get a white page with a "critical error in WordPress".
[image]

I can return back to Civi, but nothing is installed.

What went wrong? What can I do?

Thanks for help.

Regina